# How can I prevent a div from scrolling until it's clicked on?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a scrolling div on my page. My problem is that if you put the mouse cursor over that div and use the scroll wheel, it scrolls that div instead of the whole page. I'm looking for some way to **only** scroll the div after it has been explicitly clicked on, not just moused over.

Edit: Unsure why this question has been downvoted to -2, but here is my solution:

```
div.style.overflow = "hidden";
div.onclick = function() { div.style.overflow = "auto"; }
div.onmouseout = function() { div.style.overflow = "hidden"; }
```

Comment: Toggle overflow:hidden to overflow:auto on that div on click using either a class or css

Comment: can you please tell us what you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to specify overflow:hidden for that div. Then you have to write a javascript click function on that div which will make it overflow:auto. Again you have to write one more js mouseout function on that div that will make it's overflow:hidden.